# Numpy average from a large masked array

Tags: python, numpy

Whats the appropriate way to get the average value from a large masked array? Normally i would just call `.mean()` but for very large array's this fails for me.

Consider creating an array of a million elements, all with value 500, like:

```
a = np.ones(1000000, dtype=np.int16) * 500
```

Then create a random mask and combine both in a new `masked array`:

```
mask = np.random.randint(0, 2, a.size)
b = np.ma.masked_array(a, mask=mask)
```

The array `b` inherits the `dtype` and is also a `int16`.

Getting the average value from `b` can be done in different ways, but all give the same result. But the `non-ma` functions are ignoring the mask and shouldn't be used.

```
print(np.average(b), np.mean(b), np.ma.average(b), np.ma.mean(b))
(500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0)
```

But if i increase the original array size from one million to ten million, the result becomes:

```
print(np.average(b), np.mean(b), np.ma.average(b), np.ma.mean(b))
(500.0, -359.19365132075774, -359.19365132075774, -359.19365132075774)
```

Now only `np.average` **seems** correct, but as said is ignoring the mask and calculating the average over the entire array, this can be shown when changing some of the masked values with `b[b.mask] = 1000` for example. I would expect `np.mean` to do the same though.

Casting the masked array `b` to a `float32` results in:

```
b = b.astype(np.float32)
print(np.average(b), np.mean(b), np.ma.average(b), np.ma.mean(b))
(511.18945, 510.37895680000003, 510.37895680000003, 510.37895680000003)
```

And casting the masked array `b` to a `float64` (which should be done by default according to the documentation) results in:

```
b = b.astype(np.float64)
print(np.average(b), np.mean(b), np.ma.average(b), np.ma.mean(b))
(500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0)
```

So casting to a `float64` seems to work, but i would rather avoid this since it would increase the memory footprint a lot.

And while testing some of this, i also noted that calling `np.ma.average` on the non-masked array (a) gives the correct result if the size is one million and the wrong result when its ten million, while `np.ma.mean` is correct for both sizes.

Can someone explain the relation between `dtype` and the `size` of the array in this example? Its a bit of a mystery to me when this occurs and how to handle it properly.

All is done in Numpy 1.8.1 on a 64bit Win 7 machine. Installed via conda.

Here is a notebook replicating what i have done:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/RutgerK/69b60da73f464900310a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this can be shown when changing some of the masked values with `b[b.mask] = 1000` for example. I would expect np.mean to do the same though.

This is not correct, b.mask is True where there are masked values. When you assign a new value to the masked values you are unmasking them, so effectively making all the values in the array valid, you can use instead `b[np.invert(b.mask)]`.

So this should work:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones(10000000, dtype=np.int64) * 500

mask = np.random.randint(0, 2, a.size)
b = np.ma.masked_array(a, mask=mask)

b[np.invert(b.mask)] = 1000
print(np.average(b), np.mean(b), np.ma.average(b), np.ma.mean(b))
```

Which will give you the correct value except for `np.average`.

Apart from that when you are getting negative/incorrect values it's because you are getting an integer overflow. Using `dtype=np.int64` instead should solve it,

**Edit:** Another option would be to use Python integers  with `dtype=object` instead of fixed width integers, but that would be slower,this change makes `np.average` crash, but the rest of the methods work properly.

**Edit 2:** As spoken in the comments, in this case it's not necessary to increase the size of the elements of the array, we can just call `np.mean(b, dtype=np.float64)` so that `np.mean` uses a bigger accumulator to avoid overflowing.

Comment: You're right about `unmasking` assigned values, thanks for pointing that out. 
But whats overflowing? Is Numpy making a sum somewhere in the background? My values are all 500 in this example, far from the `int16` limit. If Numpy is summing somewhere, what dtype does it use? I don't get any message/error about integer overflow when running my script.

Comment: Yes, you won't get usually any notice of Integer Overflow, it's one of the dangers of using numpy, when you work with fixed width integers it's much faster but it doesn't check for overflows, so you have to keep in mind which data you are using.

In this case you are right, you can keep using int16 for your array, the problem is that `np.mean` uses by default an accumulator of the same size as the original data. You can fix it calling `np.mean(b, dtype=np.float64)` to tell `np.mean` to use a bigger accumulator instead of the same size as the original data.

Comment: Thanks. Forcing the dtype certainly works, but im not convinced about whats going wrong. The normal `mean` function works fine anyway, without setting the accumulator to float64. The `ma.mean` function works also fine, unless i specify a 'per-element' mask. This works: `np.ma.array(np.ones(n, dtype=np.int16) * 500).mean()`, this doesnt: `np.ma.array(np.ones(n, dtype=np.int16) * 500, mask=np.random.randint(0,2,n)).mean()`, for `n` is ten million. 
Is there a larger accumulator necessary if you mask elements?

Comment: Yes, according to the documentation `np.mean` and `np.ma.mean` should be equivalent, but in my system they are defined in different places and the standard accumulator size of `np.ma.sum` for the sum when calculating the mean is the standard size of an integer in the system, which may be `int32`, while for `np.mean` the standard dtype for the accumulator is `float64`.